# java - list question - Why did it print out -4 on the 3rd printout when i ran it?

Tags: java, arrays, list

```
package javaapplication8;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] list1 = {1, 2, 3,4};
     int[] list2 = {5, 6, 7,8};

     for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++){
       System.out.print(list2[i] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println("");

     list2 = list1;

     for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++){
       System.out.print(list2[i] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println("");

     //Change list1
     list1[0] = -1;

     //Change list2
     list2[3] = -4;

     //List1 output
     for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++){
       System.out.print(list1[i] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println("");

     //List2 output
     for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++){
       System.out.print(list2[i] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println("");

     //Set list1
     list1 = new int[2];
     list1[0] = 100;
     list1[1] = 99;

     //List1 output
     for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++){
       System.out.print(list1[i] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println("");

     //List2 output
     for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++){
       System.out.print(list2[i] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println("");

   }
}
```

run:

```
5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 
-1 2 3 -4 
-1 2 3 -4 
100 99
-1 2 3 -4
```

Comment: What is your first clue? Do you have a Debugger allowing you to step through your code?

Comment: I have netbean? I dont have a clue because it says for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++)
and therefore it should print out -1 2 3 4....
i dont see how the   //Change list2
     list2[3] = -4;
 has anything to do with list1...

Comment: the 
     list2 = list1;
is for the "for" loop before and it has been closed already. so should it affect it still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List 1 and List 2 are pointing to same array object after you do List2 = list1;

so doing List2[3] = -4; actually does it for array object that earlier was pointed by List1.

and remember the array object that was earlier related to List2 now stands for garbage collection.

So earlier when u did List1 = x and List2 = y there were two array objects in the memory pointed out by list1 and list2 variables. However after doing list2 = list1 u made both variables point to x array and the other array is free now and java will need to recollect this memory sometime and hence whatever changes ur doing is done to object x rather than y

Comment: so if you change list2 in any way shape or form way later down the line. you are basically changing list1 since they are referencing the same point? is that right?

Comment: yes you are right. The only thing that needs to get clarified is there are objects that recide in memory and then there are variables pointing to these objects so next time look for where your variable is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `list2 = list1;` in Java, you're not actually copying the array, you're copying a reference to that array.

So you have only one array in memory, and both your `list` and `list2` are pointing to that array. So any modification done to any of the variables also affects the other one.

If you want to create a copy of an array, have a look at the `System.arraycopy` method.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays are stored by reference, thus after calling
    list2 = list1;
both variables reference the same array. Use `list2 = Arrays.copyOf(list1, list1.length)`.